# Faster deep cloning

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone want a framework/class which allows me to clone by values .Net objects? I'm only interested with public read/write properties (namely DataContracts), and I don't care if references are resolved correctly (i.e. collecions which contains the same instance of item twice).

I tried serialization trick via `DataContractSerializer` (serialize to XML and back), wrote reflection-based cloning class (sometimes faster/sometimes slower), and was wondering if someone wrote a helper class which can do this via Emit and not reflection. As for now emitting IL is a little to much for my little brain, but I guess this would be the ultimate solution. Unless someone knows an alternative method which is faster than DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Are you working with individual objects? Or object trees/graphs?

Comment: Object trees/graphs - like I said, don't care about duplicated references but objects are nested, i.e. they do not contain only flat value properties but also other data contracts.

Comment: try this: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deep%20Cloning&referringTitle=Home

Comment: If you need the best possible performance and don't mind additional generated code, check out [CGbR Code Generator](https://github.com/Toxantron/CGbR#cloneable)

Comment: DeepCloner by force-net is extremely fast (2021): https://github.com/force-net/DeepCloner

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/ReubenBond/DeepCopy . Clones around 20x faster (my simple POCO objects) than the reflection based monstrosity I came up with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are talking about an object tree/graph:

Writing specific IL to serialize an object is tricky. IMO, your best bet is to look at a full serialization, like how `DataContractSerializer` would work - but not necessarily with that engine.

For example, [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) has a `Serializer.DeepClone<T>` method that might help. It should be faster than `DataContractSerializer`, at least. At the current time, you need to add some clues for the serializer (even if just `[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields=ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]`) - however, the current (incomplete) work-in-progress offers POCO support without attributes.

---

If you are talking about individual objects:

There are fairly simple things you can do here with `Expression` in .NET 3.5; build a dynamic `Expression` based on reflection, and call `.Compile()`. [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) has this already:

```
DestType clone = PropertyCopy<DestType>.CopyFrom(original);
```

With .NET 2.0/3.0 (without `Expression`) you might consider [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) for similar purposes.

Comment: Ok, so far I've tested AutoMapper which is actually 4 times slower than DataContract serialization, fast reflections from The Instruction Limit suggested by sambo99 are 2 times faster and protobuf is 3 times faster than DataContract. 

Marc, can you please elaborate on this: 

"the current (incomplete) work-in-progress offers POCO support without attributes." 

I cannot make it work without ProtoContract from featured version of protobuf. Thanks.

Comment: I did say it was incomplete! Basically, the "lessgenerics" branch (which doesn't work yet; don't try it) has a separate mechanism for defining the members, etc - obviously *defaulting* to attributes as the fallback. So *at some future point* you would be able to use a closed source type by saying "treat this type like so..." - a bit like the massively overloaded ctor to XmlSerializer.

Comment: Actually, if your data-contract specifies the Order on each member, then it will use [DataContract]/[DataMember] happily...

Comment: Yes, I read this in protobuf documentation but it somehow does not work. I mean when I don't specify anything I've got an exception that contract is necessary. When I specified DataContract/DataMember a new object is created but nothing is copied. When use [ProtoContract(ImplicitFields=ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]) everything works as expected. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Sorry Marc, didn't notice your remark about Order. Everything works fine.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'm just wondering whether you still need the proto-buf attributes for the deep clone to work? I'd like to include a deep clone in a library without any overhead for external classes to know about proto-buf.

Comment: @Ian if it is in-proc, you might find BinaryFormatter simpler. There is some convention-based stuff in protobuf-net, and it can be configured to work without attributes - but I'm not sure it is worth the trouble for arbitrary "external classes"

Comment: @MarcGravell: It is in-proc but it's something that I do potentially 1000's of times (because unfortunately I can't make my classes immutable without some quite ugly code) so I was looking for something faster than the BinaryFormatter which is what I currently use. I'd thought about IL cloning but haven't found an example that does this recursively for references so thought protobuf-net might be an easy answer.

Answer (score 24):

I have written three deep clone methods for .NET some time ago:

- One uses the well-known `BinaryFormatter` technique (though I tweaked it so that objects do not need to be serializable in order to be cloned). This was by far the slowest.
- For the second I used pure reflection. It was at least 6 times faster than cloning with the `BinaryFormatter`. This one could also be used on Silverlight and the .NET Compact Framework.
- The third one uses Linq Expression Trees (for runtime MSIL generation). It is 60 times faster than the `BinaryFormatter` technique but has a setup time of approximately 2 milliseconds for the first time each class is encountered.

[image: Logarithmic scale illustrating cloning performance]

The horizontal axis shows the number of objects cloned (though each cloned object includes several nested objects).

The `BinaryFormatter` is labeled "Serialization" in the chart. The data series "Reflection" is a custom one that copies fields via `GetField()`/`SetField()`.

I published all three cloning methods as Open Source here:

http://blog.nuclex-games.com/mono-dotnet/fast-deep-cloning/

Comment: I'd be curious how serialization busing protobuf-net compares against these three.

Comment: I'm getting System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime. using ExpressionTreeCloner. Any clue why?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I've done some benchmarks. Excluding setup time and file system accesses, ProtoBuf-net completes in 2/3rds of the time of the `ReflectionCloner` and is just 5 times slower than the `ExpressionTreeCloner`.

Comment: Is the horizontal axis the # of objects?

Comment: Is the data series labelled "reflection" the one that was BinaryFormatter? Thanks

Comment: @DaveInCaz Yes, horizontal shows the number of objects cloned (though each cloned object includes several nested objects)  The BinaryFormatter is labeled "Serialization" here. "Reflection" is a custom one that copies fields via GetField()/SetField().

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of libraries that do this operation. You can see benchmark results [here](https://github.com/force-net/DeepCloner#performance):

In short words, if you need peformance, do it manually, it really faster. Also, some libraries allows to peform *shallow* cloning (by the question, it is good variant for you), which is faster. And do not use `BinaryFormatter` if you need any performance.

Also, @frakon mentions that Expressions trees have same speed as IL Emit, it is slightly incorrect. Expressions Tree is slightly slower, but it can be used in partially trusted app.

Manual  13ms

DeepCloner (IL Emit) 167ms

DeepCloner (Expressions) 267ms

CloneExtensions (Expressions) 560ms

NClone 901ms

Clone.Behave! 8551ms

GeorgeCloney 1996ms

Nuclex.Cloning n/a (Crashed)

FastDeepCloner 1882ms

BinaryFormatter 15000ms

Answer (score 5):

There is probably no full working cloning code made by IL Emit on the internet.

But IL Emit is of the same speed as code by Expression Trees, because both methods end up with similar compiled lambda copy functions. Expression Trees are approximately **4x faster than Reflection**. The best thing is that **Expression Trees general cloning function is available on the internet**.

One implemetation by expression trees [was already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013490/2094687) by Cygon. New  thoroughly tested implementation can be found in the CodeProject article
**[Fast Deep Copy by Expression Trees (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111658/Fast-Deep-Copy-by-Expression-Trees-C-Sharp)**.

Use the extension method by

```
var copy = originalObject.DeepCopyByExpressionTree();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) or [BLToolkit Mapping](http://bltoolkit.net/Doc/Mapping/MapFieldAttribute.htm)

Comment: AutoMapper is not recommended for object cloning as its creator himself indicates: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/340

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether this suits your requirements exactly, but you could also create a deep clone using a [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx). See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519461/cloning-listt/519512#519512) to a related question (by [Binoj Antony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33015/binoj-antony)):

```
public static class GenericCopier<T>
{
    public static T DeepCopy(object objectToCopy)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, objectToCopy);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T) binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is considerably slower than dynamic method based serialization.   (about 10x slower at least)

Comment: @sambo99: Is there a performance comparison available? I only found one comparing standard serialization methods (http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2007/08/05/performance-comparison-of-most-popular-serializes.aspx)

Comment: @divo see: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance .. Marc uses Dynamic Method based serialization in protobuf .net

Comment: I just added my own benchmark results for three different deep cloning methods to my post. You weren't far off with your 10x slower estimate :)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Method based serialization will be fastest. (Generate a dynamic method using light weight codegen and use it for serialization)

You can do 1 method per property/field or one method for the whole object. From my benchmarking doing 1 per property does not give you too much of a performance hit.

See the following code, to see how I do this in Media Browser: http://code.google.com/p/videobrowser/source/browse/trunk/MediaBrowser/Library/Persistance/Serializer.cs

There are also some unit tests there.

There is fast reflection sample on theinstructionlimit that does exactly what you want.

see:

http://theinstructionlimit.com/?p=76

Comment: Do you have a fresh link for your Serializer example?

Answer (score 0):

The [CGbR Code Generator](https://github.com/Toxantron/CGbR#cloneable) can generate an implementation of [`ICloneable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) for you. All you need is the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CGbR/) and a partial class definition that implements `ICloneable`. The generator will do the rest for you:

```
public partial class Root : ICloneable
{
    public Root(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }
    private int _number;

    public Partial[] Partials { get; set; }

    public IList<ulong> Numbers { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return Clone(true);
    }

    private Root()
    {
    }
} 

public partial class Root
{
    public Root Clone(bool deep)
    {
        var copy = new Root();
        // All value types can be simply copied
        copy._number = _number; 
        if (deep)
        {
            // In a deep clone the references are cloned 
            var tempPartials = new Partial[Partials.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < Partials.Length; i++)
            {
                var value = Partials[i];
                value = value.Clone(true);
                tempPartials[i] = value;
            }
            copy.Partials = tempPartials;
            var tempNumbers = new List<ulong>(Numbers.Count);
            for (var i = 0; i < Numbers.Count; i++)
            {
                var value = Numbers[i];
                tempNumbers[i] = value;
            }
            copy.Numbers = tempNumbers;
        }
        else
        {
            // In a shallow clone only references are copied
            copy.Partials = Partials; 
            copy.Numbers = Numbers; 
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very fast:

Install  Newtonsoft Json and use

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T DeepCopy<T>(this T self)
    {
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well! you could write your own Clone Method wich you could specify to ignore or include properties by its attributes. 
My new library in the link down, uses reflection and FieldInfo to clone the object recursively. 
i have added it to CodeProject so you will have access to its code soon which you could modify it to your needs.

Try it out its very fast and clean, you will love it.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastDeepCloner/1.0.1

or 

PM> Install-Package FastDeepCloner