# BinaryFormatter deserialise malicious code?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I've heard there are [safety questions over the BinaryFormatter.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/is-it-safe-to-binary-deserialize-user-provided-data)

I send user-generated files to the server from the client. These are serialized classes that are then read by the server.

From my understanding of the above link, this is dangerous. But I've tried sending disposable classes, and even tried a class that implemented ISerilizable. But both were rejected due to the server not knowing the source assembly.

```
[Serializable]
public class Ship : ISerializable
{
    public Ship()
    {

    }

    public Ship(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

So how could a client successfully get code into my server via this vector? By faking the namespace name and public key causing the server to try deserialise it, thus running the above code? Or are there more subtle ways to do it?

This feature is a core fundamental to my game unfortunately so I want to be careful.

Comment: They can probably send you any of your own classes that happen to be marked Serializable. I think that's dangerous.

Comment: Is it your requirement to use the `BinaryFormatter`, or to serialize your data? Or to serialize your data in Binary?

Comment: Serialization works on data, not code. If *your* code is vulnerable to malicious input, then yes, this could be another way to attack it - just like any other way of injecting malicious data. Besides, the answers to the original post were mostly speculation, inapplicable comments on Java serialization or really contrived examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization works on data, not code. A deserializer extracts the data from the payload you provide, consturcts a new object instance and sets the object's values from the extracted data. It does NOT extract any code from the payload.

If your code is vulnerable to malicious input in the first place, then yes, deserialization could be another way to attack it - just like any other way of injecting malicious data.

For example, if you construct SQL statements by concatenating strings, you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attack whether the strings come from user input or deserialized data. The way to fix this is to use parameterized queries, not avoid deserialization or try to sanitize the user's input.

In any case the answers to the original post were mostly speculation, comments on Java serialization that's not really relevant to .NET or really contrived examples.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question but I'm not quite satisfied with the accepted answer.

> Serialization works on data, not code. [...] It does NOT extract any code from the payload.

It's not that simple. `BinaryFormatter` uses assembly qualified names to identify types. During the deserialization those type names are resolved by `Type.GetType`, which happily loads any assemblies. Therefore, a manipulated stream can load a prepared assembly, whose module initializer is immediately executed (but the malicious code can be placed in a serialization constructor or `[OnDeserializing]`/`[OnDeserialized]` method, too). [This video](https://youtu.be/kz7wmRV9xsU?t=1640) demonstrates how to exploit this to open a PowerShell and a web page in a browser.

> In any case the answers to the original post were mostly speculation, comments on Java serialization that's not really relevant to .NET or really contrived examples.

Maybe just because the answer is too old, but today there are a lot of known `BinaryFormatter` attacks. Some examples:

- [`TempFileCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.tempfilecollection) can be exploited to delete files (only in .NET Framework). This is also mentioned in the linked video (and also in the post linked in the question).
- [`StructurelEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.structuralcomparisons.structuralequalitycomparer) can be used to cause a `StackOverflowException` or a hopelessly slow hash code calculation (DoS attack). Starting with .NET Core this type is not serializable anymore.
- A lot of `[Serializable]` types that don't implement `ISerializable` (so they are restored just by setting their fields) can be initialized with invalid data.
- Even most types that implement `ISerializable` don't validate the incoming `SerializationInfo` for all possible attacks. For example, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can throw an `OutOfMemoryException` if the value of the `HashSize` entry is manipulated.
- But `BinaryFormatter` is vulnerable at a deeper level, too. For example, arrays are handled internally (and it cannot be even overridden by a surrogate selector) and a manipulated length information can also cause an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I actually believed that `BinaryFormatter` can be made safe. I even opened an issue about this topic here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/50909

But considering that security was never in focus when serializable types were implemented and it would be an enormous task to fix all these issues I can understand that `BinaryFormatter` will be [obsoleted](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md) in the future versions.

And though I introduced a [`SafeMode`](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/9195b9f9b42e396e9e6ec090dadd1265329615e1/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/Serialization/Binary/_Enums/BinarySerializationOptions.cs#L168) option in [my binary serializer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization), it cannot be completely safe as long as the serializable types themselves are vulnerable. Supporting many types natively can just reduce the threat (which is also good for producing [very compact payload](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T7BUyB)) but it cannot eliminate it in general.

**Verdict**: binary serialization is safe only when both serialization and deserialization is performed in the same process. In any other case you need to implement some additional security (eg. by signing the stream cryptographically) to be completely safe.

Comment: Seven years ago I'd have complained you didn't answer my question, now I realise my question was itself wrong. You're completely right that my base assumption that serialisation sent the whole class was wrong, and yet there are many other ways to abuse the `BinaryFormatter` in other ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `BinaryFormatter` serializes **fields** and not **methods**.

The only way to transmit and load unknown code is to:

1. Receive an assembly and load it using `Assembly.Load`.
2. Use a `CodeDomProvider` to emit IL at runtime.