# Is there an easy way to convert a ListArray into a byte array in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to convert a ListArray into a byte array in C#? The ListArray is coming from a dictionary object and contains a ListArray of objects where the underlying type is int. The only way I could get it to work was by looping thru the ListArray and individually inserting into the byte array. I was trying to get it to work with ToArray but I kept getting a cast error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int intLoop;
    byte[] arrByte;
    string strJson = "{\"Data\":[104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100]}";
    Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    //deserialize json into dictionary object
    dic = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(strJson);

    //convert arraylist into byte array
    intLoop = 0;
    arrByte = new byte[((System.Collections.ArrayList)dic["Data"]).Count];
    foreach (var s in (System.Collections.ArrayList)dic["Data"])
    {
        arrByte[intLoop] = Convert.ToByte(s);
        intLoop++;
    }

}
```

Comment: JSON deserialization is built-in to the framework (at least if you're using .NET Core / .NET 5+), no need to use this legacy API. Also, the correct way to use it would be to create a model with a `Data` property of type `List<byte>`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Any particular reason *why* you want to use `ArrayList`? It really shouldn;t be used anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach, but, if you prefer, you could use a LINQ one-liner instead:

```
ArrayList data = ...;

var arrByte = data.Cast<int>().Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
```

Note: `Cast<int>()` is required because your code uses the legacy `ArrayList` type. If your source type already implements `IEnumerable<int>` (for example, a `List<int>` or an `int[]`), you can skip this step.

Comment: Sorry your answer gives only 11 bytes(the same is array length) , mine is 72. I guess because all number are less than 256. I don' t know which is true, trying to make some research

Comment: If you try this array  var data= [104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,308,300] you will see very strange result.

Comment: @Serge: I believe it's because you used `BinaryFormatter`, which dumps type information, field names and object ids into the stream. When using generic types the overhead can be really [brutal](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T7BUyB).

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I think the question is not correct. byte[]=int[] when all numbers are less 255. After this we will see an an overflow in one of  the number are bigger 255

Comment: This data is coming from a file that has been converted to a byte array so the data should always be less than 256.

Comment: @Heinzi That works, I'm impressed by anyone who can figure out linq syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @Heinzi I wonder why the dictonary object uses the ArrayList in this case?

Comment: @Madison320: Because `JavaScriptSerializer` is a legacy API from the old days when dinosaurs roamed the earth (ok, maybe not that old, but close). Back in those dark days, we didn't have generic lists, and now they can't change the behavior of JavaScriptSerializer because that would break backwards compatibility. If you can, use Newtonsoft.Json (or the new Json classes from .NET 5+) instead.

Comment: @Heinzi Hey, I had a pet dinosaur. I'm going to upgrade right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that int[] and  byte[] are the same when all numbers are less 255. If  one  of the numbers is large than 255 it will throw exeption during conversion.

If you need byte[]

```
string strJson = "{\"Data\":[104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100]}";

var byteArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootData>(strJson);
```

class

```
public class RootData
{
    public byte[] Data {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: +1 for using an object model instead of just serializing to a dictionary. I wonder if this can be simplified by declaring `Data` directly as `byte[]` (and skipping all the conversion stuff)...

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks, I added your answer to mine, if you don't mind

Comment: In my case I'm probably stuck using the dictionary<string,object>. I simplified my example but in reality there are many more data entries of different types in my actual dictionary object.

Comment: Are you sure you want to recommend using `BinaryFormatter`? It is planned to be [removed](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md) from .NET due to its [security flaws](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide). Once I collected some of the mayor issues in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107584/5114784) answer.

Comment: I know this, but the problem is what PO wants. You int[] and  byte[] are the same when all numbers are less 255. If  one  of the numbers is large than 255 it should throw exeption.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would write it (using c# 9 language features)

```
public record MyDto(IEnumerable<int> Data);


var json = "{\"Data\":[104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100]}";
var document = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyDto>(json);
var bytes = document?.Data
        .Select(i => (byte) i)
        .ToArray();
```

1. Create data structure to represent the input data
2. Parse it with `System.Text.Json` JsonSerializer (the new standard json serializer)
3. Convert it with LINQ

Comment: I'll have to check out that json serializer. I was just using the first one I found. :)

Comment: I thought "better way" may include "do not use legacy components" ;-)

Comment: int[] and byte[] are the same when all numbers are less 255. If one of the numbers is large than 255 it should throw exeption.  So you don' t need any select, just change IEnumerable<byte>

Comment: `IList<>` would break immutability of the dto, so I'd use `IEnumerable<byte>` instead. But one could argue that the correct representation of the json is a collection of numbers and the requirement to convert this to bytes comes later. Or it's 1:1 and directly deserializing to the final type is the better approach. I think `IEnumerable<byte>` is the better solution here but I didn't test it that's why I don't update the answer.