# Best ( and quick ) way to do serialize & why my StructLayout make my code crash?

Tags: c#, serialization

I wrote some abstract class that support quick serialize and deserialize.
I add StructLayout to the implementation class and i got crash ( without the StructLayout its working with no crash )

I have 2 question

1. Is there is any better fest way to do the Serialize ( on this i do serialization in TotalMilliseconds = 0.4834 and using the standard way of .net i takes TotalMilliseconds = 2.120 ) ?
2. Why the 'StructLayout' crash my code ( exception on the runtime at the start of the application running

{"Could not load type 'WindowsFormsApplication4.Element1' from assembly 'WindowsFormsApplication4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the format is invalid.":"WindowsFormsApplication4.Element1"}

The code

```
public abstract class SerializeElement
{
    public abstract void Serialize(BinaryWriter bw);
    public abstract void DeSerialize(BinaryReader br);

    public sealed byte[] Serialize()
    {
        byte[] retVal = null;

        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using(BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                Serialize(bw);
                retVal = ms.GetBuffer();
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public sealed void DeSerialize()
    {
        byte[] retVal = null;

        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms))
            {
                DeSerialize(br); 
            }
        }
    }
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
public class Element1 : SerializeElement 
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
    public int Var2 { get; set; }

    public override void Serialize(BinaryWriter bw)
    {
        bw.Write(Var1);
        bw.Write(Var2);
    }

    public override void DeSerialize(BinaryReader br)
    {
        Var1 = br.ReadInt32();
        Var2 = br.ReadInt32();
    }
}


    static void Main()
    {
        Element1 e = new Element1()
        {
            Var1 = 1,
            Var2 = 2
        };

        var tt = e.Serialize();
```

Comment: No inner exception? Are you able to reproduce the problem without actually doing any serialization?

Comment: What are you using the StructLayout for? I can't see anything here that uses it. The question is valid, though.

Comment: the StructLayout  is because the code is part of system that get struct from c++ code. and in the C++ code the definition is using pragma pack= 4

Comment: no inner exception - ad without doing the serialization - ( just create Element1 without calling serialization method ) the crash is there also

Comment: why are you trying to serialize bits at a time, why not the entire structure?

Comment: because using BinaryFormatter is slow - and on this way i can do it fester

Comment: `StructLayout` has no impact on the serializer because you never serialize the class, just 2 integers

Comment: StructLayout  has impact because when you are make the serialize  you will create struct of pack 4 --- if you will do the same with struct instate of class you will see it .. but on struct i can't use abstruct class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the answer is just a click away ... the StructLayout definition don't give the inherited option

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a little testing, I found out that .Net doesn't like the fact that `Element1` inherits from `SerializeElement` while having the `StructLayout` attribute applied.

*When I commented out* inheriting from `SerializeElement`, the program ran fine. So, I suggest that you create a [Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that encapsulates the properties used by `Element1` and uses `StructLayout` attribute. Then, provide a conversion to a class that inherits `SerializeElement` so that you can serialize and deserialize that value.

You will need to make sure that the output is formatted correctly, but that shouldn't be too much of a problem.

In terms of [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) being the fastest solution, I would *[assume](https://xkcd.com/1339/)* so. [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) is a simple abstraction over a [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) that just provides utilities for converting values to/from `int`/`float`/`double`/etc. values. But, the important part is knowing when you **need** the fastest solution. Time and time again, we(programmers) find out that sometimes the fastest solution isn't the best one. Often, the trade off of speed for development pace and quality is worth it.

With that said, I would recommend ([as would others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4143614/1832856)) that you try using [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). It is quite fast, and (in my opinion) the benefits of a general purpose serializer far outweigh having to write custom serializers for *every* single one of your classes.

Comment: 10x - i know about the StructLayout and the inherits .. but still looking the reason. 

using objectPool with those element give on my case the best way to do it ( i get network package each 20 millisecond )

Comment: @Yanshof Yeah, I don't think many people know the answer to why StructLayout is killing the app. I have a feeling that the problem has to do with StructLayout-related code that gets run when `Element1` gets loaded, but there's not much of a way to know apart from looking at some of the decompiled code.