# c# Binaryformatter slow

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I've used BinaryFormatter in order to serialize/deserialize objects to a byte array. But it's too slow. Here's my code:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
stream.Close();
byte[] currentByteArray = stream.ToArray();
```

Is it possible to improve that code, in order to speed it up. Or what is my alternatives? I've seen several other serializatiors like xmlserialization but I don't want to write it to file, just as a byte array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the class code and the metrics in your question.

Comment: also, how big is teh serialized data? what size are we talking about here?

Comment: `stream.Close();` should be *after* `byte[] currentByteArray = stream.ToArray();`, not *before*

Comment: Are you serializing dataobjects? like for communication?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko No. It should be in a `finally` block after the `.ToArray()`. In fact, stream should just be in a `using` block.

Comment: The data is serialized down to 10MB, it takes about 200ms. Yes it's data objects used in communication.

Comment: Suggest you try [running a profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) and seeing what it tells you.  To get started check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx).  There's not enough information in your question for us to see if you're doing anything specifically bad with `BinaryFormatter`.  See [Fastest way to serialize and deserialize .NET object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143421) for comparisons between serializers.

Comment: An [alternative serializer](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T7BUyB) (disclaimer: written by me) can be a solution. But please note that using binary serializers have [security implications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019995/5114784) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be improved if you place disposing in `finally` statement like guys said in comments:

```
IFormatter formatter;
MemoryStream stream;
try
{
    formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream = new MemoryStream();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
    byte[] currentByteArray = stream.ToArray();
}
finally
{
   if(stream!=null)
      stream.Close();
}
```

However, the above code does not improve performance of `BinaryFormatter` class cause it works and is used correctly. But you can use other libraries.

One of the fastest and general purpose serializer in .NET is [Protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net). For example:

```
[ProtoContract]
class SubMessageRepresentations
{
   [ProtoMember(5, DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)] 
   public SubObject lengthPrefixedObject;
   [ProtoMember(6, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
   public SubObject groupObject;
}

[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields=ImplicitFields.AllFields)]
class SubObject { public int x; }


using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
  _pbModel.Serialize(
   stream, new SubMessageRepresentations {
        lengthPrefixedObject = new SubObject { x = 0x22 },
        groupObject = new SubObject { x = 0x44 }
   });
byte[] buf = stream.GetBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
Console.Write("{0:X2} ", buf[i]);
}
```