# VS 2017 .NET Core BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Is with VS 2017 released in the .NET Core tools BinaryFormatter included? When I create a .NET Core console application I cannot find BinaryFormatter. There are many Nuget packages but which one is the right one to get a working BinaryFormatter with .NET Core?

By the way it is a bit awkward to create with a released Visual Studio a project which does not compile. I need to start a cmd shell where my .NET Core console application resides and do a

```
dotnet restore
```

to get it to compile. Did I miss a VS command in the references menu?

**Edit1**

Using `Install-Package BinaryFormatter` gives me an exception

```
PM> Install-Package BinaryFormatter
Restoring packages for d:\source\vc17\NetCoreApp\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2.csproj...
Install-Package : Package BinaryFormatter 1.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package BinaryFormatter 1.0.2 supports:
  - dnx451 (DNX,Version=v4.5.1)
  - dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package BinaryFormatter
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package BinaryFormatter
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConsoleApp2'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package BinaryFormatter
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: It is [work in progress](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/10144).  Seems targeted for the 1.2.0 release right now.  There are still a lot of very basic things wrong in the VS2017 release, I'm going to wait for the proverbial version 3.

Comment: Seems like it. But since it is open source I could compile it via sources directly I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**

Thanks to @ClockEndGooner for pointing out, that People who are using .Net-Core 2.1 or later there is a Binary Formatter Located in:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
```

[Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BinaryFormatter/) is a nuget package for that it says it supports core as well:

```
Install-Package BinaryFormatter
```

I'm not sure if this contains what you need but is also the System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters

```
Install-Package System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters
```

These packages work with .Net-Core 1.0 in order for them to work with a 1.1 enviroment you will require cross comiplation you can reference this [Core Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17528)

Comment: This gives me an exception. Is there no <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>  compatible nuget package?

Comment: Hmm, seems they haven't updated to use Core1.1 yet lets see what is an alternative

Comment: @johnny5 Neither of these NuGet packages support .NET Core 1.1.

Comment: @GyleIverson,  Don't just downvote because this answer does not fit your problem, You need to cross compile, see updated answer

Comment: @johnny5 Thanks for the additional information on cross compilation. I up voted the answer based on the new information.

Comment: @GyleIverson thank you, I always try to update my answers as soon as someone comments issue, but can see how my answer was unclear. I hope this fixes the issues

Comment: @johnny5 The latest System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters package supports .NET Core 1.1, but it doesn't implement the BinaryFormatter object yet.

Comment: @GyleIverson from the discussion you should be able to reference the formatters from 4.3.0.  Because they are not dependent on  the old runtime.  It appears like JamesNK got this working in Json.net

Comment: Alternatively can't you reference the formatters in 4.5.2. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38846600) on how to extend the support.

Comment: For .NET Core 2.1 and later, BinaryFormatter is in the System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary namespace.

Comment: Thanks I’ve edited my answer to provide the new information