# Binary converter misses mscorlib on ARM

Tags: c#, docker, serialization, .net-core, binaryformatter

I have a telegram bot written in c# and using .net-core 2.1. Now I am trying to run this application in a docker container on a raspberry pi. During the run I save a configuration file using the formatter `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary`. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42704419/3795043) this binary formatter should be included in .net-core 2.1, right? But writing using the binary formatter fails with this exception. (Reading seems to work although the file is incomplete since writing always fails):

```
Exception when writing the modules: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.Converter' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can run the application on windows 10, in a container in docker for windows 10 and on hypriot linux on the raspberry with ARM. The exception only happens in the docker container on the raspberry pi.

Any idea how I can solve this? Will I have to switch to a different serializer even though the binary formatter is supposed to be included in .net-core 2.1? I come from java and the easiest included approach there is binary so I just used it in c# as well.

You can find the whole project in [this github project](https://github.com/lehrbaumm/telegram_bot/tree/feature/dotnetcore2.1). The file dockerARM contains the docker configuration for docker on the raspberry pi. If you want to run the application you need a telegram bot API key. The whole docker-compose build log including the exception can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/EJQBVn3X). There are a bunch of errors in the dotnet publish step I can't say I understand them. But the step succeeds.

Comment: are you referencing anything else that is using that? like a .net framework dll?

Comment: I think you're not using the right version... that's a .NET Framework DLL, you probably want to use a .NET Core DLL

Comment: How would I specify which one to reference? The .csproj file is quite short, only 4 references and none of them are dlls. I am sorry I do let visual studio care about the referencing and don't look into the files so much myself. Is there a different place where references are defined?