# Faster way to clone

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-2.0, cloning

I am trying to optimize a piece of code that clones an object:

```
#region ICloneable
public object Clone()
{
    MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    formatter.Serialize(buffer, this);     // takes 3.2 seconds
    buffer.Position = 0;
    return formatter.Deserialize(buffer);  // takes 2.1 seconds
}
#endregion
```

Pretty standard stuff.  The problem is that the object is pretty beefy and it takes 5.4 seconds (according ANTS Profiler - I am sure there is the profiler overhead, but still).

Is there a better and faster way to clone?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're trying to clone.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852064/faster-deep-cloning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Don't implement ICloneable.
2. The fast way to clone an object is to create a new instance of the same type and copy/clone all fields from the original instance to the new instance. Don't try to come up with a "generic" clone method that can clone any object of any class.

Example:

```
class Person
{
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private int age;

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, int age)
    {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person Clone()
    {
        return new Person(this.firstname, this.lastname, this.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree.  I'd also like to add an option (3), use an immutable type so that you don't *need* to clone.

Comment: Using [CGbR](https://github.com/Toxantron/CGbR) gives you the same result without the need to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer: There ARE better methods for cloning.**

*Reflection* or *Expression Trees* are much faster then *Serialization* (reflection is **5x faster**, expression trees are **20x faster**).

[image]

If you use **[this linked cloning function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111658/Fast-Deep-Copy-by-Expression-Trees-C-Sharp)** as an extension method, each your cloning code shrinks to

```
#region ICloneable
public object Clone()
{
    return this.DeepCopyByExpressionTree();
}
#endregion
```

To use the extension method it is enough to have the file *DeepCopyByExptressionTrees.cs* anywhere in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, streams, even inner ones like this, are expensive.
Have you tried to just create a new object it and update the relevant fields to bring the object to the same state? I find it hard to believe your method takes less time.

Comment: It's rather the reflection used to do the serialisation and deserialisation that is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty expensive way to clone. The object never gets on the wire, so all the time doing serialisation is basically wasted. It will be way faster to do memberwise clone. I realise it's not an automagic solution, but it'll be the fastest.

Something along these lines:

```
class SuperDuperClassWithLotsAndLotsOfProperties {
  object Clone() {
    return new SuperDuperClassWithLotsAndLotsOfProperties {
      Property1 = Property1,
      Property2 = Property2,
    }

  public string Property1 {get;set;}
  public string Property2 {get;set;}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because manually copying fields is the fastest way I created a code generator, that reads your class definition and generates a clone method. All you need is the [CGbR nuget package](https://github.com/Toxantron/CGbR) and a partial class that implements `ICloneable`. The generator will do the rest.

```
public partial class Root : ICloneable
{
    public Root(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }
    private int _number;

    public Partial[] Partials { get; set; }

    public IList<ulong> Numbers { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return Clone(true);
    }

    private Root()
    {
    }
} 

public partial class Root
{
    public Root Clone(bool deep)
    {
        var copy = new Root();
        // All value types can be simply copied
        copy._number = _number; 
        if (deep)
        {
            // In a deep clone the references are cloned 
            var tempPartials = new Partial[Partials.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < Partials.Length; i++)
            {
                var value = Partials[i];
                value = value.Clone(true);
                tempPartials[i] = value;
            }
            copy.Partials = tempPartials;
            var tempNumbers = new List<ulong>(Numbers.Count);
            for (var i = 0; i < Numbers.Count; i++)
            {
                var value = Numbers[i];
                tempNumbers[i] = value;
            }
            copy.Numbers = tempNumbers;
        }
        else
        {
            // In a shallow clone only references are copied
            copy.Partials = Partials; 
            copy.Numbers = Numbers; 
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

And the partial class

```
public partial class Partial : ICloneable
{
    public short Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return Clone(true);
    }
}

public partial class Partial
{
    public Partial Clone(bool deep)
    {
        var copy = new Partial();
        // All value types can be simply copied
        copy.Id = Id; 
        copy.Name = Name; 
        return copy;
    }
}
```