# AspNet different webservices, one custom class, generating different custom classes in client

Tags: asp.net, web-services, namespaces

Good morning Sir,

I'm trying to figure out why my clients are generating different namespaces for my custom class (ok, the question is not exactly why, but if I can change this behaviour somehow).

The general example is here:
In my backend, I have two distinct webservices

- Menu.asmx
- Category.asmx

The class declaration of theses wbservices seems like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace backend.webservices
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Category : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public List<CategoryType> GetFeaturedCategories(int idRegion, int idLanguage)
        {
            return CategoryService.GetFeaturedCategories(idRegion, idLanguage);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public CategoryType GetCategory(int idCategory, int idLanguage, int idRole, int idUser, int idRegion, bool generateBreadCrumb)
        {
            return CategoryService.GetCategory(idCategory, idLanguage, idRole, idUser, idRegion, generateBreadCrumb);
        }

    }
}
```

Both webservices have methods that return a custom class: CategoryType.cs

And my CategoryType smells like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
[Table("CATEGORY")]
public class CategoryType
{
    [Column("ID_CATEGORY")]
    public int? idCategory { get; set; }

    [Column("ID_REGION")]
    public int? idRegion { get; set; }

    [Column("IN_STATUS")]
    public int? inStatus { get; set; }

    [Column("IN_MENU_SUPERIOR")]
    public int? inMenuSuperior { get; set; }

    [Column("NR_ORDER")]
    public int? nrOrder { get; set; }

    [Column("IN_CATALOG")]
    public int? inCatalog { get; set; }

    [Column("IN_FEATURED")]
    public int? inFeatured { get; set; }

    [Column("TX_MONGO_ID")]
    public string txMongoId { get; set; }

    //EXTERNAL
    [Column("NM_CATEGORY")]
    public string nmCategory { get; set; }

    //NON ENTITY
    public List<CategoryType> subCategories = new List<CategoryType>();

    public List<BreadCrumbType> breadCrumb;
}
```

The "problem" is that when I import these webservices in my frontend (service reference) It duplicate my custom class in the clients, so, in the code I have two classes CategoryType.cs:

- WSMenu.CategoryType
- WSCategory.CategoryType

What's annoying is that it cannot convert from one type to another, like this:

```
WSMenu.CategoryType myExampleCategory = WSCategory.GetMyExampleCategory(idCategory);
```

Obviusly, this is just a example, if a have a single code line, this is not a real problem.
The problem comes when the project start to growth, in this case, I will have a lot of instances of theses classes comming from a lot of places.

Thanks in advance and have a good day!
And please, ignore some gramatical errors, I'm trying hard to learn English.

**EDIT:**

So, I have found that I can "convert" my objects, or I can write a converter using reflection (new object.properties = oher object.properties) but I don't want to do this, if there is a way to not do this, I will be happy

[2 objects, exactly the same (except namespace) c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788827/2-objects-exactly-the-same-except-namespace-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, because my classes have custom attributes, I cannot simply create a Reflection Mapper, in this case, I have to create my own "mapper" for each custom class I want to convert:

```
using MenuCategoryType = frontend.WSMenu.CategoryType;
using MenuBreadCrumbType = frontend.WSMenu.BreadCrumbType;
using CategoryCategoryType = frontend.WSCategory.CategoryType;
using CategoryBreadCrumbType = frontend.WSCategory.BreadCrumbType;

/// <summary>
/// converte objetos CategoryType de namespaces diferentes
/// </summary>
public class CategoryMapper
{
    public static MenuCategoryType Convert(CategoryCategoryType origin)
    {
        if (origin == null)
            return null;

        return new MenuCategoryType()
        {
            idCategory = origin.idCategory,
            idRegion = origin.idRegion,
            inCatalog = origin.inCatalog,
            inFeatured = origin.inFeatured,
            inMenuSuperior = origin.inMenuSuperior,
            inStatus = origin.inStatus,
            nmCategory = origin.nmCategory,
            nrOrder = origin.nrOrder,
            txMongoId = origin.txMongoId,
            breadCrumb = Convert(origin.breadCrumb),
            subCategories = Convert(origin.subCategories)
        };
    }

    public static CategoryCategoryType Convert(MenuCategoryType origin)
    {
        if (origin == null)
            return null;

        return new CategoryCategoryType() {
            idCategory = origin.idCategory,
            idRegion = origin.idRegion,
            inCatalog = origin.inCatalog,
            inFeatured = origin.inFeatured,
            inMenuSuperior = origin.inMenuSuperior,
            inStatus = origin.inStatus,
            nmCategory = origin.nmCategory,
            nrOrder = origin.nrOrder,
            txMongoId = origin.txMongoId,
            breadCrumb = Convert(origin.breadCrumb),
            subCategories = Convert(origin.subCategories)
        };
    }

    public static MenuBreadCrumbType[] Convert(CategoryBreadCrumbType[] origin)
    {
        if (origin == null)
            return null;

        MenuBreadCrumbType[] target = new MenuBreadCrumbType[origin.Length];
        for(int i=0; i < origin.Length; i++)
        {
            target[i] = new MenuBreadCrumbType() {
                idCategory = origin[i].idCategory,
                nmCategory = origin[i].nmCategory
            };
        }
        return target;            
    }

    public static CategoryBreadCrumbType[] Convert(MenuBreadCrumbType[] origin)
    {
        if (origin == null)
            return null;

        CategoryBreadCrumbType[] target = new CategoryBreadCrumbType[origin.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < origin.Length; i++)
        {
            target[i] = new CategoryBreadCrumbType()
            {
                idCategory = origin[i].idCategory,
                nmCategory = origin[i].nmCategory
            };
        }
        return target;
    }

    public static MenuCategoryType[] Convert(CategoryCategoryType[] origin)
    {
        if (origin == null)
            return null;

        MenuCategoryType[] target = new MenuCategoryType[origin.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < origin.Length; i++)
        {
            target[i] = Convert(origin[i]);
        }

        return target;
    }

    public static CategoryCategoryType[] Convert(MenuCategoryType[] origin)
    {
        if (origin == null)
            return null;

        CategoryCategoryType[] target = new CategoryCategoryType[origin.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < origin.Length; i++)
        {
            target[i] = Convert(origin[i]);
        }

        return target;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm not marking my own answer as Correct answer just because this is a workaround to the problem.