# How to copy List in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I want to copy a List of Objects, but i keep getting references between the objects.

```
List<MyClass> copy = original;
```

When i change the value in the copy List, the original List ends up modified also.
Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519461/cloning-listt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
List<MyClass> copy = original.ToList();
```

This would make an element-by-element copy of the list, rather than copying the reference to the list itself.

Comment: @ricojohari Could you please be more specific about the "not working" part?

Comment: when i changed the value of the copy list, the original list is getting modified too

Comment: @ricojohari Right - that's because the copy is *shallow*. If you add or remove items to/from the original, the copy is not going to "see" that change. However, changing mutable objects inside the list would be reflected in the copy as well.

Comment: would deep copy maintain the value in the original list even if the copy list is modified?

Comment: @ricojohari Yes. If you want a deep copy, use `List<MyClass> copy = original.Select(v => new MyClass(v)).ToList();` (assuming that `MyClass` has a "copy constructor" that takes an instance of the same class and returns a "deep copy" of the object).