# Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<byte[]>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<byte[]>>

Tags: c#

I tried to clone a List<byte[]> without reference but I get this error when I try to run the code:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<byte[]>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<byte[]>>

This is the code that I wanted to run:

```
newList = new List<List<byte[]>>(oldList).ToArray();
```

Does this even work, or are there other solutions?

Comment: I think so too : newList = (List<byte[]>)oldList.ToList();

Comment: A `List<byte[]>` is not a `List<List<byte[]>>`. Specifically, the [List constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) you're using expects an `IEnumerable<T>`, which in this case is an `IEnumerable<List<byte[]>>` according to your code. Though I'm not sure why [`newList = oldList.ToList();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15330708/3181933) isn't suitable in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
newList = new List<List<byte[]>>(oldList).ToList();
```

Comment: Changing `.ToArray()` to `.ToList()` doesn't magically make `oldList` an `IEnumerable<List<byte[]>>`, as would be needed for this to work at all. From the error message, `oldList` is a `List<byte[]>`.