# C# error with generic interface and class

Tags: c#, oop

I have clases and interface like this:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public interface IMove<T>
{
    void ChangeLocation(T obj);
}

public class Move<T> : IMove<T>
{
    public void ChangeLocation(T obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And I can do stuff like this:

```
        IPerson p = new Person();
        IMove<Person> t1 = new Move<Person>();
        IMove<IPerson> t2 = new Move<IPerson>();
```

But when I'm trying to do:

```
IMove<IPerson> t3 = new Move<Person>();
```

compiler is showing error:

`Cannot implicity convert type Move<Person> to IMove<IPerson>`

Can you please explain why so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# generic inheritance and covariance part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/) and  [Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/) and [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/) and [still confused about covariance and contravariance & in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/) and [C# : Is Variance (Covariance / Contravariance) another word for Polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078423/)

Comment: To protect giraffes: `List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe>{new Giraffe()}; List<IAnimal> animals = giraffes; animals.Add(new Lion());`

Comment: Here you have two problems: you have Move<> and IMove<> AND Person and IPerson. You can't convert Move<Person> to IMove<IPerson> as is, or the opposite. You can try for example Linq Select or any other thing by hand like [Copying a List<BaseClass> to List<DerivedClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516463/copying-a-listbaseclass-to-listderivedclass/516475) and [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass)

Comment: Thank you all, Now I understand it. @TimSchmelter I love your example :)